# Does enum retain its associated object?

Tags: swift

I am curious if the next code will lead to the strong reference cycle?

```
enum Type {
    case some(obj:Any)
}

class Entity {
    var type:Type
    init() {
      type = Type.some(obj:self)
    }
}
```

Comment: That code cannot create a reference cycle because 1) no object is created, 2) the code does not compile at all.

Comment: @MartinR, right. Treat it as pseudocode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. `Any` is implicitly strong. If you pass a reference type, it will be a strong reference. It's not quite a "cycle" since nothing "retains" an enum, but as long as the value exists (or any copy of the value), it will hold onto `Entity` and prevent it from being deallocated.

Imagine if it were not true. What would `.some(obj: NSObject())` contain? If `Type.some` did not increase the retain count, the `NSObject` would vanish. (Since this is very similar to an `Optional`, that would be very surprising, since many `T?` would immediately become `nil`.)

BTW, this is easily and usefully explored by creating a `deinit` method on `Entity`.